# Switch scene on Mobile device?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wonder how fast and efficient is it to switch scene in the Mobile device? most of my elements are UI, someone said switch scenes in Android will be as efficient as Activity, which I am pretty skeptical about.

Comment: Try it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

well, the statement of

> switch scenes in Android will be as efficient as Activity

will make no sense, because, In unity3d, there is only one activity `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer` there, and the efficiency of switching between scenes depends on how many resources and other staff will be loaded, and if switching between scenes becomes a big concern, you should consider building things in just one scene and making them active/inactive instead.